# How do I convert Coin Market Cap API data from JSON to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, coinmarketcap

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import APIKEY

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

parameters = {
    'start': '1',
    'limit': '10',
    'convert': 'USD'
}
headers = {
    'Accepts': 'application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': APIKEY.KeyAPI,
}

jsondata = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers).json()

CoinDF = pd.read_json(jsondata)

CoinDF.to_csv(r'/home/USER/Documents/CoinData.csv')
```

I am trying to get the Pandas to read the JSON data that the API returns but when I run this program I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/CoinMarketCapAPI.py", line 24, in <module>
    CoinDF = pd.read_json(jsondata, orient='index')
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 199, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 540, in read_json
    json_reader = JsonReader(
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 622, in __init__
    data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 659, in _get_data_from_filepath
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 558, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/home/crow/PycharmProjects/CoinTracker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 371, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

The connection to the API is working but for some reason I can't get Pandas to read what it is given.

Thank you for your help

Edit:

So I have done some tinkering with it and I think the hang up is the structure of the JSON file.

It seems to be a list of dictionaries but there is at least one set of nested dictionaries in there. like this...

```
[string1{blah:blah},string2{blah:blah,blah:blah,Nest{nest1:nest2}}]
```

. When I just tried reading this from JSON to a dataframe I think it choked on the second level of dictionaries. I suppose the question is now how to make nested dictionary keys their own columns in Pandas

Edit 2: For some reason the JSON file uses single quotes instead of double quotes and I think that is messing everything up. I will leave the question up if someone has a good answer but I am not sure if there is a good solution to this.

Final Edit:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import KeyStuff
import json

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

parameters = {
    'start': '1',
    'limit': '10',
    'convert': 'USD'
}
headers = {
    'Accepts': 'application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': KeyStuff.APIKey,
}

resp = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers)
jsondata = json.loads(resp.text)
CoinDF = pd.json_normalize(jsondata['data'])

CoinDF.to_csv("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Junk\\CMCAPIDF.csv")
```

Here is the final functional code. Thank you very much to Jonathan Leon!

Comment: Did you check `jsondata` to see if it gives you a valid object?

Comment: I have updated the error in the description. It seems like when I tinker with it Python views it as a dictionary or maybe a list but I am new to JSON so I don't know if Python will recognize JSON as its own data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's good documentation here: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

try something like this (because I'm not exactly seeing what you are, you may have play around a little bit).

```
resp = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers)
jsondata = json.loads(resp.text)
CoinDF = pd.json_normalize(jsondata['data'])
```

A couple thoughts: pesonally, i have never used `read_json()` from an api response, but that may be just personal preference, but sometimes it just doesn't work. an alternative is `pd.DataFrame(your_data)`, but that doesn't always work to parse correctly. It's my go to though. But for this one I think they wrap this in a list so `json_normalize()` works great.

Also, when receiving api responses, you should look closely at the structure. You may or may need the `status` key, but you really want the `data` key, hence the `jsondata['data']`

Comment: I will look into this. 

The status key only links to connection information between my computer and the API so I don't really need it. I have already done some trouble shooting and the connection seems fine

Comment: Edit: I receive an error that says ```Attribute Error: 'dict" object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: What happens when you remove the .text?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. The .text still seems to be necessary but I trimmed a lot of the program down and this seems to do the trick. Thank you again

Comment: Excellent. Good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

test with telegram bot API, that returns type of json response. it works

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
rs = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot105574XXXXYYYYSSSXXXXXA/getupdates')

#Actually the data is <class 'dict'>, so enclose with pd.DataFrame.from_dict() works.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(rs.json()), orient='columns')
df.to_csv('api.csv')
```

Comment: This kind of works. I am able to get the text into the dataframe but it isn't divided into columns and rows

Comment: i have written a custom class for such task, please check this gist (example included)
https://gist.github.com/omikabir/244802d4de269f0b9b24eed42ec2b326
which takes json/dict as argument and can return dataframe. where every key converts into column and value into rows.